# Query com data em variável no MySQL retornando vazia

Tags: mysql, sql, query, datetime

Preciso fazer um consulta no MySQL setando 3 variáveis,quando sé no caso de numero inteiro da certo,mais quando incluo data ta retornando vazia.

Segue minha *query*,o que poderia estar fazendo errado?

```
SET @tipo    = 47;
SET @dataini = 2016-03-17;
SET @datafin = 2016-03-17;
    SELECT 
      * 
       FROM sale 
            WHERE  start_time BETWEEN '@dataini' AND '@datafin' 
               AND sale_type = @tipo
```

Segue o resultado da consulta, sem usar as variáveis:

```
2   44  346479  2016-03-17 17:44:58 0   0   47  0   10.000  0.000   0   0   395 0   0.000   0.000   0.000   11962677.200    0.000   2016-03-17 16:47:51 2016-03-17 17:44:58     2016-03-17  0   0       0   0.000   0   0   0   1458243445  1458243508  1458244061  
2   44  346483  2016-03-17 17:55:56 0   0   47  0   10.000  10.000  0   0   395 35  0.000   0.000   0.000   11962677.200    0.000   2016-03-17 16:58:57 2016-03-17 17:55:56     2016-03-17  0   0       0   0.000   0   0   0   1458244642  1458244678  1458244720  
2   44  346510  2016-03-17 18:48:33 0   0   47  0   10.000  10.000  0   0   621 0   0.000   0.000   0.000   11962906.700    0.000   2016-03-17 17:51:38 2016-03-17 18:48:33     2016-03-17  0   0       0   0.000   0   0   0   1458247805  1458247848  1458247877  
2   44  346513  2016-03-17 18:50:29 0   0   47  0   10.000  0.000   0   0   621 0   0.000   0.000   0.000   11962906.700    0.000   2016-03-17 17:53:25 2016-03-17 18:50:29     2016-03-17  0   0       0   0.000   0   0   0   1458247931  1458247977  1458247992
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Não sei se tem outros problemas, mas deve colocar a data entre aspas. Do jeito que estava ele fazia a conta 2016 menos 3 menos 17.

```
SET @tipo    = 47;
SET @dataini = '2016-03-17';
SET @datafin = '2016-03-17';
    SELECT 
      * 
       FROM sale 
            WHERE  start_time BETWEEN @dataini AND @datafin 
               AND sale_type = @tipo
```

Faço o seguinte teste:

```
SET @tipo    = 47;
SET @dataini = '2016-03-17';
SET @datafin = '2016-03-18';
    SELECT 
      * 
       FROM sale 
            WHERE  start_time BETWEEN @dataini AND @datafin 
               AND sale_type = @tipo
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/SQL/Select/BetweenDates.sql).

Quando o horário é usado, não pode especificar só da data, tem que colocar o horário todo que deseja na faixa. Ou tem que usar datas que contemplem todos os horários de um dia. `'2016-03-17'` é o mesmo que `'2016-03-17 00:00:00'`

Nem acho que seja o ideal em todas situações, mas poderia fazer a *query* como [nesse **SQLFiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/454b8e/3).